suspend-then-hibernate not continuing to hibernate mode ubuntu 24
I have been chasing this issue for several days and I've been unable figure it out. I trying to use suspend-then-hibernate to make my laptop go to sleep and then hibernate after a delay. I am able to suspend and hibernate my laptop individually but suspend-then-hibernate is having problems. It goes to suspend but it will not continue to hibernate automatically. Then, when I push some keys to wake the laptop from suspend, it then finally initiates the hibernate sequence. This is not the expected behavior, I would expect it to go into hibernate automatically after the delay without any user input.
The log shows that the laptop suspends fine but then doesn't hibernate until after I wake it up manually. (Note that I have configured my HibernateDelaySec=10 for debugging.)
Here is my sleep.conf
[Sleep]
AllowSuspend=yes
AllowHibernation=yes
AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
#AllowHybridSleep=yes
SuspendMode=suspend
SuspendState=mem standby freeze
HibernateMode=shutdown
#HibernateDelaySec=3600
HibernateDelaySec=10
#SuspendEstimationSec=60min
SuspendEstimationSec=10

Note that I am on systemd version 255.4 which should have the commit for issue 25269.
Happy to try and ideas, thanks in advance!
Log (truncated to fit character limit)
Sep 25 12:11:33 linda systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend-then-hibernate.service - System Suspend then Hibernate...
Sep 25 12:11:33 linda systemd-sleep[29088]: /etc/systemd/sleep.conf:24: Support for option SuspendMode= has been removed and it is ignored
Sep 25 12:11:33 linda rtkit-daemon[1964]: Successfully made thread 3122 of process 3105 owned by '1000' high priority at nice level 0.
Sep 25 12:11:33 linda rtkit-daemon[1964]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep 25 12:11:33 linda systemd-sleep[29088]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
Sep 25 12:11:33 linda kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Sep 25 12:11:33 linda kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.003 seconds
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: Freezing user space processes
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU10: hpet wd-wd read-back delay of 265676ns
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: clocksource: wd-tsc-wd read-back delay of 135911ns, clock-skew test skipped!
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled.
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: [drm] PTB located at 0x000000F47FC00000
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: nvme nvme0: 16/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: random: crng reseeded on system resumption
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda systemd-resolved[991]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda systemd-sleep[29088]: System returned from sleep operation 'suspend-then-hibernate'.
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda bluetoothd[1087]: Controller resume with wake event 0x0
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: PM: suspend exit
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda systemd-sleep[29088]: Performing sleep operation 'hibernate'...
Sep 25 12:12:08 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: hibernation entry
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.003 seconds
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Freezing user space processes
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: Basic memory bitmaps created
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: Preallocating image memory
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: workqueue: vmstat_update hogged CPU for >13333us 4 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: Allocated 1378574 pages for snapshot
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: Allocated 5514296 kbytes in 3.85 seconds (1432.28 MB/s)
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: MODE2 reset
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP off
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: CPU 15 is now offline
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: Creating image:
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: Need to copy 1412962 pages
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: Normal pages needed: 1412962 + 1024, available pages: 2218538
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: AMD-Vi: Virtual APIC enabled
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: AMD-Vi: Virtual APIC enabled
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C001: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP always-on
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU1 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C002: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU2 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C003: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU3 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x4
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C004: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU4 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x5
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C005: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU5 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x6
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C006: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU6 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C007: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU7 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x8
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C008: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU8 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x9
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C009: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU9 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0xa
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00A: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU10 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0xb
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00B: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU11 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 12 APIC 0xc
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00C: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU12 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 13 APIC 0xd
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00D: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU13 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 14 APIC 0xe
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00E: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU14 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 15 APIC 0xf
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00F: Found 3 idle states
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: CPU15 is up
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled.
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: [drm] PTB located at 0x000000F47FC00000
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: [drm] PSP is resuming...
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: nvme nvme0: 16/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb 3-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: [drm] reserve 0x400000 from 0xf47f800000 for PSP TMR
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010028
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_low uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_high uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_0.2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 8
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 8
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 8
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 8
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 8
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Message 00020007 (seq 11) timeout
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_restore+0x0/0x110 returns -110
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: PM: failed to restore async: error -110
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: Basic memory bitmaps freed
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 12
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: done.
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: HW/SW Version: 0x008a008a, Build Time: 20240219111427
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: PM: hibernation: hibernation exit
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: HW/SW Version: 0x8a108a10, Build Time: 20240219110958a
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1c7a, idProduct=0576, bcdDevice=15.72
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb 3-3: Product: EgisTec EH576
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb 3-3: Manufacturer: EgisTec
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda kernel: usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 16D950F3
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda systemd-resolved[991]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda bluetoothd[1087]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda gnome-shell[3105]: libinput error: client bug: timer event7 hold: scheduled expiry is in the past (-997ms), your system is too slow
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda rtkit-daemon[1964]: Successfully demoted thread 3122 of process 3105.
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda systemd[1]: Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda rtkit-daemon[1964]: Demoted 1 threads.
Sep 25 12:13:10 linda systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend-then-hibernate.target - Suspend; Hibernate if not used for a period of time.


I am invoking suspend-then-hibernate directly via
systemctl suspend-then-hibernate

I have a lenovo ideapad slim5 with amd hardware (7000 series) if that helps.
ubuntu desktop running 6.8.0-45-generic

This question is similar to: How do I use pm-suspend-hybrid by default instead of pm-suspend?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This isn't about changing the default behavior to suspend-then-hibernate. This is about suspend-then-hibernate not working when invoked directly or otherwise

I have the same Problem. Hibernation only starts if a key is pressed after the hibernation-delay-time is expired in suspension. Same thing with closed lid. If i open the lid after the delay-time is expired, it goes to hibernation
